# Saving Data into Pivot Table - Many To Many Relationship - Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have successfully added my tables including my pivot table. My tables are  `managers` `categories` and `categories_manager`(pivot table).  When i save data from my categories controller, I get an error like

> "SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'system.category_manager' doesn't exist (SQL: insert into
>   `category_manager` (`category_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`,
>   `manager_id`) values (2, 2017-10-09 13:39:12, 2017-10-09 13:39:12,
>   1))`

I am a newbie anyway

PS: i have list of users saved already. Also, even though i get the error, the data is saved into the category table but not the pivot table

**Manager Model**

```
public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category')
        ->withTimestamps();
    }
```

**Category Model**

```
 public function managers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Manager')
        ->withTimestamps();
    }
```

**Category Controller**

```
public function store(CategoryFormRequest $request)
    {
        $user = User::find(1);
        $category = new Category(array(
            'category_name'  => $request->get('name'),
        ));

        $user->categories()->save($category);
        return redirect('/categories/create')->with('status','Category successfully created');


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel uses **Convention over configuration** which means by following simple conventions you avoid complicated configurations.

Name of the pivot table should consist of singular names of both tables, separated by undescore symbole and these names should be arranged in alphabetical order.

So your pivot table name should be `category_manager` but you said you created the table under the name `categories_manager`